# Rectilinear convex hull

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, orthogonality

I am working on an algorithm, which takes as input as set points contained inside the Rectilinear Convex Hull of some fixed points in 2-dimension. I tried to find an implementation but met with little success. Can someone direct me to a link where such an algorithm is discussed? An algorithm for a convex hull in euclidean space is available in Matlab, Python, Java and many languages but not in Manhattan space.

Since, I am not a mathematician by training, I might be missing some important resources in my search.

EDIT 1 :
Taking cue from Prof. Rourke's reply, I am trying to implement the algorithm to find the Upper cr-convex hull given on Page-167 of the paper [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020025584900252). Can someone explain to me what is meant by "Maximal Monotonic Increasing Sequence" in Step-2 of the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you cannot find what you seek because there is another phrase used for the same concept, *orthogonal convex hull*. E.g., there is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull):

---

[image: Wikipedia]

<sup>Wikipedia image.</sup>

---

Two papers on the topic are cited below:

> Ottman, T., Soisalon-Soisinen, E., Wood D.: On the definition and computation
>   of rectilinear convex hulls. *Information Sciences*, 33, 157–171 (1984)
>   14. Preparata, F., Shamos, M.I.: Computational Geometry: An Introduction. SpringerVerlag
>   (1985). ([Journal link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020025584900252).)

Their *cr*-convex hull definition is likely the best option. It can be computed in
optimal $O(n \log n)$ time.

> Rawlins, G.J.E., Wood, D.: Ortho-convexity and its generalizations. *Computational
>   Morphology: A Computational Geometric Approach to the Analysis of Form*,
>   137–152. Elseiver Science Publishers B.V., North-Holland (1988).

Comment: thanks. I read the paper. I will try to implement the cr-Convex hull algorithm from paper. But here at Stack Exchange, I wanted to find out if an implementation exists for cr-Convex hulls. like one that exists for Convex Hulls. Went through the topics of the book "Computational Geometry in C" but found algorithm only for convex Hulls and not Orthogonal CHs. I found that, implementation wise,  it has been picked up by the research community only recently here (http://www.matem.unam.mx/urrutia/online_papers/EurCGOnRectCONV.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the algorithm in Java for visualization purposes. You can find it on [github](https://gitlab.com/restricted-orientation-geometry/dynamic-rch). If you find it difficult to extract the actual algorithm from the code, please let me know.

You can also take a look at the $L_\infty$ package of [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PkgSegmentDelaunayGraphLinf2). The vertices of the outer face of the Delaunay triangulation in the $L_\infty$ metric are the vertices of the Rectilinear Convex Hull. So you can use that library to compute the vertices. It is an overkill, but it is a robust and ready-to-use implementation.

Finally, if want to give it a try, the algorithm is actually not that hard to implement. The vertices of the rectilinear convex hull are the maximal points under vector domination with respect to the four quadrants defined by the coordinate axes. A very easy to follow pseudo code can be found in the book from Preparata.

*Preparata, Franco P.; Shamos, Michael Ian*, Computational geometry. An introduction, Texts and Monographs in Computer Science. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. XII, 390 p. DM 148.00 (1985). [ZBL0575.68059](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0575.68059).

You can find the pseudocode in page 154. You will notice that the book does not mention anything about the rectilinear convex hull, since the connection with the set maxima problem was published later.

Comment: Hi. I notice that the github link is dead. Can you update it ?

Comment: Done. I moved all my projects to Gitlab and forgot to update this link. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Carlos ^^